# Example of non-orthogonal projection on Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Can anybody cook up an example of a projection operator $P$ on a Hilbert space $H$ that is non-orthogonal? I.e., one where $PH$ and $(1-P)H$ are *not* orthogonal subspaces of $H$.

I'm completely stumped as to whether or not this question has an answer. I would guess that $H$ would have to be non-separable, as separability automatically induces an orthonormal basis of $H$, meaning any subspace is spanned by a subset of this basis; such a property would immediately imply that $PH$ and $(1-P)H$ are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: "meaning any subspace is spanned by a subset of this basis" Not at all. You can take the projection $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ of $\mathbb{K}^2$ and extend it to a projection of $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DF noted, "any subspace is spanned by a subset of this basis" is false. The line $y=x$ in the $xy$ plane is a subspace that is not the linear span of any subset of the standard basis $e_1=(1,0), e_2=(0,1)$. One example of a projection onto this line is $(x,y)\mapsto (x,x)$. The kernel of this projection is the $y$-axis, which is at angle of $45$ degrees to the range of the projection.

Comment: Thanks guys, clarified things a lot.